# Getting regions with neighboring borders?

Tags: arcmap, shapefile

I am currently working with some shapefiles of congressional precincts of the US.

One of my objectives is to get a list of the "Neighboring" precincts for each of the precincts. For example, if precinct X shares a border with YZ then I know that X has neighbors Y and Z.

I saw that ArcMap is a very powerful tool for working with shapefiles and analyzing data.

What tool can I use to get this done?

This is how my map looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a tool which might help you.

I tested it with sample data within ArcMap 10.5 using links below.

**PolygonNeighbors_analysis**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/polygon-neighbors.htm

**How it works:**

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/how-polygonneighbors-analysis-works.htm

Output is a table which will have two main coulumns src_OBJECTID (with id of polygon) and nbr_OBJECTID (ids of polygons near).

[image]

Comment: You've linked to ArcGIS Pro documentation when the question is about ArcMap, but Polygon Neighbors is the right tool to look at.

Comment: Yes, but I tested it within ArcMap. Could not find ArcMap docs.

Comment: To find Desktop help links I search using a Google search string like 'ArcGIS polygon neighbors 10.6'.

Comment: thank you so much this is exactly what i was looking for